How to install sql files in package directory with setup.py
My python project has the following structure:
.
├── my_module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_code.py
├── sql
│   └── some_dir
│       ├── some_query.sql
│       ├── sub_dir
│       │   └── sub_query.sql
│       └── some_other_query.sql
├── README.md
├── LICENSE
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py

and the parameters to setup.py looks something like this:
package = {
      "name": "my_module"
    , "version": "1.0"
    , "packages": [ "my_module" ]
    , "package_dir": {'': './'}
    , ...
    , "data_files": ...something...
    , "package_data": ...something...
    , "include_package_data": True
    , ...
}

setup(**package)

While reading the setup-tools documentation, it is clear that the package_data entries need to reside inside a package, in other words a directory with a __init__.py file present in the root that is named in the packages entry, or else they WILL BE SILENTLY IGNORED.
It is also clear that the data_files entries will install ANYWHERE on the target system, the paths specified in the entries will be relative to the target system root, which warrants some care.
Since my sql/ directory structure is NOT inside a package directory, it cannot be installed with the package_data entry.
How can I use the data_files entry to install the sql directory somewhere it can be found by my code after install, ideally next to the code?
NOTE: I know I could just put my sql dir in a dummy package and be done with it, however I have my reasons for not doing this.

I just read that data_files is deprecated, so I guess I am screwed. Any tips welcome!
